# NodeJS request times out when sending a archiver file

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, next.js

I have a NextJS app where I have to generate loads of QR codes, 300,400,500 at a time. I want to put them inside a zip and let the user download them. Here's the code which puts the codes into a zip using the `archiver` library`:

```
  const archive = archiver.create("zip", {});

  let index = 1;
  for (const code of codes) {
    // @ts-expect-error
    const qrCode = new QRCodeStyling({
      nodeCanvas: canvas,
      width: 300,
      height: 300,
      data: code.url
    });

    archive.append(
      await qrCode.download({
        name: "testName",
        extension: "png",
        skipDownload: true,
        buffer: true,
      }),
      {
        name: `${code.name}-${index}.png`,
      },
    );

    index++;
  }

  console.log("before finalizing");
  await archive.finalize();
  console.log("after finalizing");

  return archive;
```

The request takes like 10s on a local machine, and when in production it just times out every time. The program sometimes doesn't even respond, it just hangs on `before finalizing`..

This is how I'm sending my codes to the frontend:

```
res.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment");

return res.status(200).send(await exportCodes());
```

Please note that these zip files are usually around 3-5mb, so size should not be a problem I don't think

Comment: What is the error that the website is giving you in production?

Comment: @Mallard 'Task timed out after 10.01 seconds', the website is hosted on the Vercel platform.

Comment: I don't see that you define `archive.pipe(res)`, you should define it before `archive.append()`

Answer (score 0):

When calling `qrCode.download(...)`, you create a promise, which is then `await`ed, and the result is passed to `archive.append(...)`, – only after that you get to download the next QR code. Let's say, downloading a QR code takes 100 msec. Multiply that by 300, and you get 30000 msec, or 30 seconds, – *on average*. Of course, it will time out.

You have to parallelize downloading. Create a bunch of promises, await them all together at once, then `archive.append(...)` the results one by one:

```
interface QrCodeDownloaded {
  name: string;
  index: number;

  // I don't know the type of result here, sorry; must be something like Buffer | Stream | string
  result: any;
}
```

```
  const archive = archiver.create("zip", {});
  const downloads: Promise<QrCodeDownloaded>[] = [];

  // We have to use classic for-loop here, because we want to have
  // an independent `index` variable for each iteration
  for (let index = 0; index < codes.length; index++) {
    // counting from 0 here
    const code = codes[index];

    const qrCode = new QRCodeStyling({
      nodeCanvas: canvas,
      width: 300,
      height: 300,
      data: code.url
    });

    const download = qrCode.download({
      name: "testName",
      extension: "png",
      skipDownload: true,
      buffer: true,
    });

    // We have to use .then() here, because we want to hold to
    // code names and indexes, but we also don't want to re-iterate through
    // the array again. We can't use `await` here, because this will negate
    // the whole thing, – we want to initiate the next download without
    // awaiting the current download
    downloads.push(download.then((result) => ({
      result,
      name: code.name,
      index: index + 1, // counting from 1 here
    })));
  }

  // This is the most important line, it does the parallelizing
  const results = await Promise.all(downloads);

  for (const { result, name, index } of results) {
    archive.append(result, { name: `${name}-${index}.png` });
  }

  console.log("before finalizing");
  await archive.finalize();
  console.log("after finalizing");

  return archive;
```